# Is caching as important with MongoDB as with MySQL?

Tags: c#, optimization, mongodb, caching

I am writing a C# HTTP request server for my web game and I am using MongoDB for the database. Is it more efficient to still cache whatever I can in the C# application? Or is it faster to just do a request to MongoDB for every thing. I am expecting around a dozen selection queries per minute for each active player, and maybe one or two save/update queries per minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"dozen selection queries per minute for each active player" doesn't tell us anything.  For that to have any bearing we'd need to know the number of active players, the amount of time each query is taking, the table structure, queries in use (including amount of data returned), statistics on server load, and others such as whether you are using Mongo's ability to shard the database, etc.

Regardless, before setting up any type of caching I'd highly suggest you start with profiling the system.  You need to know where your bottlenecks are, if any even exist. This isn't something you just guess at, you need hard and real statistics.

With that information in hand you can make a determination as to whether you need

- to make minor fixes to your code
- implement some type of caching strategy
- shard the database server across multiple servers
- rearchitect large swathes of code
- scale up (buy bigger servers)
- or even fix internal network issues.

Point is, don't start caching stuff in the hopes of getting a performance increase later.  Caching is just as likely to increase performance as it is to kill it depending on a huge number of factors.

---

One other thing to add here.  If you are using a web farm to host your request server then the complexity and hardware costs involved in caching data locally to each independent web server grows drastically.

Hardware costs go up due to increased memory requirements on your web server(s) when trying to keep the data cached in memory on those machines.

Complexity increases when trying to keep the cached copies in sync so that they don't become stale.  I would imagine that a game would **require** information that 100% current.  Sites like facebook and others can afford to be a little out of sync.  When a game server goes out of sync it could have negative impacts on player usability.

Assuming you are currently deploying only to a single web server and a single DB server, adding caching capabilities *now* might cause a huge amount of pain for you in the event you move to multiple web servers and/or multiple db servers.

Finally, if for some reason you are deploying only to a single machine that hosts both the database and web server then caching is completely ludicrous.

Comment: After reading your edit, I've decided to ignore caching until I finish the first release of the game. I can't tell what impact caching will have at the moment so it would make more sense to see if it helps when the game is ready.

If I finish the game and need to scale it to be able to handle more users, would sharding be a quick and effective way to solve the problem temporarily while working on optimization?

Comment: @Barakat: Sharding involves setting up additional mongo database servers and configuring them in a cluster so that each shares the load.  This has a number of advantages including removing a single point of failure.  So, I'd investigate it long before I considered any type of caching scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would say irrespective of the database, caching seldom changing data on the server is better than making a bunch of database calls. Anything that can come from the web server directly across the wire vs making a database call and then sending across the wire is a good thing. If these dozen selection queries you're making return the same data, it's better to cache it.

Comment: Sounds good... until you realize that MongoDb itself is positioned as a caching store: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases  With that in mind, caching the cache seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Aggreed with @Chris ... one of the goals of MongoDB is to have features of a database with performance closer to something like memcached's cache. 

Therefore using cache as a "first step" would not only defeat (some) of the point of MongoDB but it also might very well not be the best use of your RAM.

MongoDB will store as much data in RAM (making it nearly as fast as cache) so if you also have a competing cache in the middle you'll likely eat up all your RAM like candy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to consider: When your game is small your database will probably be on the same machine, and the database itself will do its own caching. Later on if your game is popular you will end up with multiple web servers, and it would be better to use distributed caching like memcached if you're going for overall memory efficiency.